# GCloud universal service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-identity

I have around 8 projects created under my GCloud account and it might increase in future.

I am trying to manage inventory and other activity related to all the projects from single place using automation. It becomes very critical to manage 10+ service account keys and keep rotating them in regular interval.

Is there any option to manage all projects using single service account?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grant access for a service account to any Google Cloud Platform resource you'd like. Your service account has an associated `@gserviceaccount.com` email address; you can go in the Cloud Console under the "IAM and Admin" tab and grant access to that service account to an entire project.

I'd urge you to exercise caution in doing something like that, however; the more permissions you give a service account, the more of a crisis it will cause if that account is compromised.

To read more, see:
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview

Comment: thanks!! What I am looking for is "one service account for multiple projects" is that possible?

Comment: Got it @Zachary

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread that might fill your needs: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479025/cross-project-management-using-service-account

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault - could you [edit your answer](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) to add some context to the link you give, and to make your answer stand on its own?